# How do override the camera render in Unity (or manipulate the camera matrix) to achieve this effect?

Tags: unity-game-engine, matrix, 3d, computer-vision, augmented-reality

I have made this camera calibration sketch in Processing where I can configure 6 screen points aligned with a 3D known object (cube) to get the camera projection matrix.

[video: Camera Calibration in Processing using Direct Linear Transformation](https://youtu.be/oW9gHiO1GfI)

In Processing, I can apply a matrix direct to the "scene" with just one line of code:

`applyMatrix(viewProjMatrix)`;

where viewProjMatrix matrix looks like:

```
  -4.7415   -2.3964   -2.4075  253.0431
  -2.7923    6.1067    6.1569  143.6573
   0.0000    0.0000    1.0000    1.0000
   0.0061   -0.0094    0.0145    1.0000
```

It is not a pure projection matrix as it includes model world multiplications. In fact, I don't even need a "camera" in Processing.

In Unity I can apply a custom camera projection matrix, but how can I override the whole rendering output using a matrix such as above? Is there a way to render 3D information mult by a custom matrix as in Processing?